# View all products within category lead to blank page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm on Magento 1.7.0.2. When I view all products within category, I got a blank page after loading for while and sometimes I got Internal Server Error.

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

If it works for only a few products, most probably you are running out of memory. Increase it. The recommended value is `512M`, but the more you have the better.

Comment: @gonzela2006. Try more. Also check the magento and serve error logs

Comment: @gonzela2006 is logging turned on and the directory writeable? Also the logs should be in `var/log/{system|exception}.log. Are you running any modules that could be causing overload, try disabling them most of the time I find inefficient observers are the biggest culprits.

Answer (score 0):

if you used product collection & **addAttributeToSelect('*')** on it.

**or**

**Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);**

then dont use any one

select the specific attribute which you need.
for example

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'url_key','price','lowest_price','service_id','description','short_description'));
```

because loading all attributes of product affects on big database.
 and its also affect on site performance

hope this help you